# What is ng-app Directive

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, razor, model-view-controller

What is ng-app directive in brief?

I Have tried this [ASP.NET MVC 5 With AngularJS - Part One](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/302f8f/asp-net-mvc-5-with-angularjs-part-1/).

Comment: it is used for bootstrapping the angular with html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-app directive tells AngularJS that this is the root element of the AngularJS application.

All AngularJS applications must have a root element.

You can only have one ng-app directive in your HTML document. If more than one ng-app directive appears, the first appearance will be used.

check this for more info http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-app.asp

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your app an Angular app you need to [bootstrap AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Bootstrapping is the process of intialization i.e. setting up the dependencies.

This is typically done using the [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive, the bootstrapping can also be done from JavaScript using [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

`ng-app` directive gives a developer the freedom to make the entire application as an Angular app (writing `ng-app` on the html element) or only a specific part of the application (such as writing `ng-app` only on a particular div/container)

When we talk about `ng-app` directive we sure need to discuss about Modules as well. A module is a container for different parts of your application, A module can depend on other modules and you always have a main module as opposed to having a main method like in a C# Console Application.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-app` is a starting point for the `Angular application`, also we can say `ng-app` will be the root element of the app. For better understand

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp